# Angular2 web and Angular2/Nativescript apps seem to have inconsistent behaviour when using the exact same Rest service

Tags: rest, angular, nativescript, angular2-nativescript

I am busy with a very basic Angular2/Nativescript app.  I Use a RestService to talk to a local API  and seem to be having some inconsistent results.  This Rest Service is also used by a web app without any issues.  When I call the ping(ip: string) function to test the IP address of the local server I get an error, when I console.log it the output of the error is:

JS:  TypeError: error.json() is not a function

Any idea what this means?  Is there any way to debug/see what's going on using Nativescript?
The only difference between my mobile app and webb app that I can think of is that each uses a different version of Typescript, could this have anything to do with my issue?

```
The ping function that doesn't work on the mobile app:

ping(ip: string) : Observable<any> {
      let tempUrl: string = "http://" + ip + "/BRMServices/WebEnquiry/ping";      
      return this.http.get(tempUrl)
      .map((res: Response) => res.json())
      .catch((error: any) => Observable.throw(error.json().error || 'server error'));
  }  


 The following function works perfectly on the mobile and web apps:

 getProduct(barcode: string): Observable<ProductModel> {          
      return this.http.get('http://10.60.160.34/BRMServices/WebEnquiry/' + "/POSEnquiry/" + barcode)
      .map((res: Response) => res.json())
      .catch((error: any) => Observable.throw(error.json().error || 'Server error'));
  }

  The Nativescript app uses Typescript V2.0.2,
  The webb app uses Typescript V~2.0.3
```

Comment: Remove this -- .catch((error: any) => Observable.throw(error.json().error || 'Server error')); try to log on .subscribe(result=>{//something },error=>{console.log(error);} )

Comment: @Habeeb  The strange thing is that the other function works fine even with the catch statement...

Comment: Problem is ping function return error response which is not in json.

Comment: @Habeeb I now get the following after removing the catch and adding console.log in the res of the subscribe:
 Response with status: 200  for URL: null

Comment: So i'm guessing it's success seeing as it's a 200ok?  Also why would this be caught as an error?

Comment: May be check . console.log(tempUrl). Also check the response in postman

Comment: @Habeeb  It seems my backend is only returning the text alive for the /ping endpoint so i'm guessing it's throwing an error as the response isn't a Json?  Does that sound likely to you?  If you think that's it please add your answer so I can accept it, I wouldn't have seen that 200 response without your help:)

Comment: No problem man.;)